# MIPS Syscalls and $t registers

Tags: assembly, mips, system-calls

MIPS registers have a convention - $s registers are to be preserved across subroutine calls, so if your subroutine modifies them, it should save them to the stack, while $t registers are not preserved.

Now, can a syscall potentially modify a $t register? In a simulator I have, it doesn't, but could a real machine have the $t registers change, potentially? I ask because I want to know
whether it's safe to assume a $t register will remain the same across a syscall.

Comment: What Operating System?  Would it not depend on the implementation of a specific OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not wise, unless documented, to rely on *any* call preserving specific registers.

If the doco for the syscall states that it only modifies certain registers, that's a contract with your code. If it breaks that contract, it's a bug (although probably easier for you to fix in your own code than wait for the developer). If it states nothing of the sort, *don't* depend on it, convention or otherwise.

Well-written calls will preserve *all* registers that aren't specifically used to return you information. But, if you're not sure, and you need that register preserved, do it yourself before calling the syscall.

Answer (score 1):

> Now, can a syscall potentially modify a $t register?

Yes!

Of course, your operating system's syscall interface may preserve all these registers. But there's no technical reason why a syscall *can't* modify them. Check the documentation of your OS.